# Использование bootstrap markdown

Tags: html, bootstrap, markdown

Суть проблемы такова, я подключаю markdown к своему редактору, он прекрасно работает, показывает превью и все очень хорошо.

Но как дело доходит до отправки и выводе текста с базы данных на страницу я замечаю что текст не форматируется под разметку.

Пример:

Я ввожу: ### Тест

Он выводит: ### Тест

Т.е без форматирования, а должен выводить заголовок 3 уровня.

Вот мой div класс где есть вывод текста с базы.

```
  <div class="message__body">
     <div class="content_message">
        <?php echo nl2br($item['ticket_message']) ?> // ТУТ ВЫВОД КОНТЕНТА
     </div>
  </div>
```

Пожалуйста подскажите что делать надо, может какие-то скрипты надо написать?

У меня нет вывода parseContent ибо я не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: Не нужно дублировать вопросы по три раза, можно было просто добавить необходимую информацию в предыдущий вопрос (один из предыдущих вопросов). Специально для этого под вопросами есть ссылка "править".

Comment: @insolor вы сможете помочь с моим вопросом ?

Comment: С вопросом - да, могу направить почитать [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). С ответом - нет.